# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Trying to get the value of a Json but keep throwing me this error.

[image]

This is the code:

```
string djson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);


            var httpContent = new StringContent(djson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(Baseurl + "ex.api/api/exmaple/indi/getindicertification", httpContent);
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var messageResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Messages>(jsonString);
            var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultingRequest>(jsonString);
```

I also try this way too but keep trowing me a error too:

```
var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultingRequest>>(jsonString);
```

My model class looks like this:

```
public class ResultingRequest : EvaluationResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public int CertificationRequestStatus { get; set; }
    public int Language { get; set; }
    public string OGPCorrelationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmissionDate { get; set; }
    public object Reason { get; set; }
    public object Owner { get; set; }
    public string OGPATGNumber { get; set; }
    public object SolicitantName { get; set; }
    public object SolicitantIDNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public bool CommitedToPRACSES { get; set; }
    public object Resolution { get; set; }
    public object Kiosco { get; set; }
    public object Comments { get; set; }
    public bool PorAcuerdo { get; set; }
    public int KioscoId { get; set; }
    public string EvaluationResult { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the Json:

```
{
"ResultingRequest": {
    "Id": 123 ,
    "UserId": 3456 ,
    "RequestDate": "09-20-2019",
    "CertificationRequestStatus": 4,
    "Language": 1,
    "OGPCorrelationID": "",
    "EmissionDate": "",
    "Reason": null,
    "Owner": null,
    "OGPATGNumber": "",
    "SolicitantName": null,
    "SolicitantIDNumber": null,
    "ExpirationDate": "",
    "CommitedToPRACSES": false,
    "Resolution": null,
    "Kiosco": null,
    "Comments": null,
    "PorAcuerdo": false,
    "KioscoId": 1,
    "EvaluationResult": "Negative"
},
"EvaluationResult": {
    "SolicitantIsMinor": false,
    "EvaluationResults": [],
    "IndividualHasNoCases": true,
    "IndividualDeceased": false,
    "CertificationType": "Negative",
    "RestrictedIndividual": false
},
"CertificationPDFBytes": "",
"SentByEmail": true,
"SentByEmailSuccess": true,
"Message": null,
"CertificationKey": ""
}
```

I want to get the value "EvaluationResult" from the ResultingRequest:{}. What do I do wrong or what I'm missing? I try a couple of ways I search for this but all the ways I keep receiving an error.

Comment: "Id": "",
    "UserId": "",

Comment: RequestDate will fail also. An empty string is not a valid date.

Comment: @Ralf I just erase the value for confidential propose. I just post the Json just for the view of the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you Deserializing into a List your json request should be an array of ResultingRequest which right now he isn't because its an json object you have to add the [] to your json request.
Example:

```
[{
"ResultingRequest": {
    "Id": "",
    "UserId": "",
    "RequestDate": "",
    "CertificationRequestStatus": 4,
    "Language": 1,
    "OGPCorrelationID": "",
    "EmissionDate": "",
    "Reason": null,
    "Owner": null,
    "OGPATGNumber": "",
    "SolicitantName": null,
    "SolicitantIDNumber": null,
    "ExpirationDate": "",
    "CommitedToPRACSES": false,
    "Resolution": null,
    "Kiosco": null,
    "Comments": null,
    "PorAcuerdo": false,
    "KioscoId": 1,
    "EvaluationResult": "Negative"
}}]
```

Secondly the rest the json will not be parsed since they aren't a ResultingRequest object, and finally like they mention here you weren't specifying some property values

Edit: Since you are saying that the request is being sent by an API and you don't wanna change the json format what you can do the following , parse the JSON into a JObject ( since your json it's an object and not an array ) then select which object you want to retrieve ( in your case its the ResultingRequest ) then deserialize it like so :

```
     var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
     var resultingRequestJson= parsedObject["ResultingRequest"].ToString();
     var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultingRequest>(resultingRequestJson);
```

I made a simple example of your json file and got some other further errors and to fix it I changed the Datetime properties into nullable because your json file its returning empty strings example:

```
public DateTime? EmissionDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: The json is come like that without [] just with {}. New at this sorry.

Comment: It's fine just let me know where you struggling after changing the json to have an array or simply deserialize a ResultingRequest  instead of list

Comment: I generate the Json with an API then I want to Deserialize to grab the "EvaluationResult" form "ResultingRequest": {. Like this var messageResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Messages>(jsonString); is work fine.

Comment: change  to var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultingRequest>(jsonString); since you are not returning an array of it

Comment: Yas!! finally thank you so much for that extraordinary explanation and step by step!! is working perfectly fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is wrong, note that the first attribute in your Json (`Id` and `UserId` are missing quotes)
Try to use it this way:

```
[{
  "ResultingRequest": {
    "Id": "",
    "UserId": "",
    "RequestDate": "",
    "CertificationRequestStatus": 4,
    "Language": 1,
    "OGPCorrelationID": "",
    "EmissionDate": "",
    "Reason": null,
    "Owner": null,
    "OGPATGNumber": "",
    "SolicitantName": null,
    "SolicitantIDNumber": null,
    "ExpirationDate": "",
    "CommitedToPRACSES": false,
    "Resolution": null,
    "Kiosco": null,
    "Comments": null,
    "PorAcuerdo": false,
    "KioscoId": 1,
    "EvaluationResult": "Negative"
  },
  "EvaluationResult": {
    "SolicitantIsMinor": false,
    "EvaluationResults": [],
    "IndividualHasNoCases": true,
    "IndividualDeceased": false,
    "CertificationType": "Negative",
    "RestrictedIndividual": false
  },
  "CertificationPDFBytes": "",
  "SentByEmail": true,
  "SentByEmailSuccess": true,
  "Message": null,
  "CertificationKey": ""
}]
```

Comment: The value is a int that's why come with out "".

Comment: Then you need to add a value, you can leave em empty. Add 0 if you want

Comment: That Json comes with all values but I erase for confidential propose I just add it like that to see the structure of the Json.

Comment: Ok then I suppose after getting the values and setting em, no problems have to occur when deserializing the object. Just simply you can't put empty (non-typed) elements inside of a json string, just like that: `{"Id":}`. And for further working use http://jsoneditoronline.org/ if you want to check a Json if is correct or not

Comment: The Json I receive is from an API then I want to Deserialize to grab a value from the Json.

Comment: Yes I did. I just did what Tigo tell me to do.